# Why do classes with no constructor arguments need parenthesis

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I started off learning programming/OOP in PHP. To the best of my knowledge of best practices in PHP, you can instantiate a class without parenthesis if it does not take any arguments.

Such as

```
$class = new Class;
```

As opposed to:

```
$class = new Class();
```

I am starting to expand my skills into python and wasted about 5 hours yesterday trying to figure out why a function wouldn't pass an argument even though it was ridiculously simple. My Code:

```
class MainViewWidgets(MainViewContainer):

    def __init__(self):
        # instantiating like this prevents MainViewController.getHeaderItems from returning the arg passed to it, however the code still "works" in some sense
        self.controller = MainViewController 

        #this works
        self.controller = MainViewController()

    def createHeaderOptionCheckbox(self, pane):
        self.header_string = StringVar()
        header_checkbox = ttk.Checkbutton(pane, text='Data Contains Headers', variable=self.header_string, onvalue='headers', offvalue='keys')
        self.header_string.trace('w', self.headerOptionCheckboxChanged)
        return header_checkbox

    def headerOptionCheckboxChanged(self, *args):
        print(self.header_string.get())
        #will print "headers" or "keys" on checkbox toggle
        print(self.controller.getHeaderItems(self.header_string.get()))
        #prints "default"

class MainViewController:

    def __init__(self):
        self.CheckFile = CheckFile()
        get_config = GetConfiguration('config.ini')
        self.config_file = get_config.getProperty('directory', 'input_file')
        self.csv = CSVReader(self.config_file)
        self.chosen_index = None

    def getHeaderItems(self, header='default'):
        return header
```

Can someone please help me understand why in Python you need to instantiate a class with parenthesis even if there are no constructor arguments other than `self`. Also, why did the `MainViewController` still kind of work, but it did not behave as I wanted it to? As in it was loaded, and the functions "did things", but it would not seem to accept arguments. Is there any advantages of instantiating a class without its parenthesis?

Please note, I do not need help getting this code to work, I just want to understand why this happens.

Comment: Because it is the way Python syntax is defined.

Comment: try `merp = MainViewController; print(merp())` :P

Comment: The long and short of it is you can pass around classes just as well as you can pass around class instances. So `self.controller = MainViewController` assigns the `class` MainViewController to self.controller. If you wanted an instance, you need the parens.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely clears it up for me.

Comment: You can even [get real meta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) with python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can someone please help me understand why in Python you need to instantiate a class with parenthesis even if there are no constructor arguments other than self.

The reason is simple: when you instantiate an object, you are actually *calling* its class (which is itself an object), and you call objects using `()`.

In python, *everything is a first-class object*, even classes (and functions!) themselves. In order for a class to be a first class object, it follows that the class needs its own class ([metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)) to define its behavior. We call the class of a class "metaclass" so as to avoid confusion when talking about classes and classes of classes.

To answer the second part of your question: "things" were happening when you used `MainViewController` instead of `MainViewController()` because `MainViewController` *is a full-fledged object*, just like any other object.

So you might ask: what is the class - actually the metaclass - of the `MainViewController` object?

---

As you know, you can create a class like this:

```
class MyClass: 
    pass
```

When you do this, you are in actuality creating a new instance of the [metaclass known as `type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type).

Note that you can create the same class this way; there is literally no difference between the below and the above:

```
MyClass = type('MyClass', (object,), {})
```

---

The `type` metaclass is the base metaclass of all classes. All python "new style classes" (not so "new" anymore since they were implemented in python 2.1, I believe) are of the class `type`:

```
print(type(MyClass)) # type
print(type(list)) # type
print(type(int)) # type
# Note that above, type is being used as a "function" (it's really just a callable)
```

Interestingly enough, `type` is even its own metaclass:

```
print(type(type)) # type
```

So to reiterate: the class `MyClass` is actually an instantiation of `type`. It follows, then, that *calling* the class results in running the `__call__` method of its metaclass.

When you do:

```
obj = MyClass()
```

...you are *calling* `MyClass`, which results (in the background) in running the method `type.__call__()`.

This is the case with all user defined classes, btw; if you include the `__call__` method in your class, your class is callable, and the `__call__` method is executed when you call class instances:

```
class MyCallable():
    def __call__(self):
        print("You rang?") 

my_instance = MyCallable()
my_instance() # You rang?
```

You can see this in action. If you create your own metaclass by subclassing `type`, you can cause things to happen when an instance of the class based on your custom metaclass is created. For example:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "call: {} {} {}".format(self, args, kwargs)
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

# Python 3: 

class MyClass(metaclass = MyMeta):
    pass

# Python 2: 

class MyClass():
    __metaclass__ = MyMeta
    pass
```

Now when you do `MyClass()`, you can see that the `__call__` method of `MyMeta` happens before anything else (including before `__new__` AND before `__init__`).

Comment: This is true, and informative, but not really an answer.

Comment: I chose to focus on the first question since it seemed to be the main concern.

Answer (score 2):

Because function calls require `()`. When you do `MyClass()`, you are calling `MyClass`. The expression `MyClass` evaluates to the class itself, which is an object.